# How can I play Civilization 6 as Korea?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm trying to start a game as the Korea civ. According to [this list of Civilizations](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Civilizations_(Civ6)) in the game, Korea *should* exist, but it's nowhere to be found when I create a game. Why not? How do I play as Korea?

Answer (score 51):

Korea is exclusive to the Rise & Fall expansion pack for Civilization 6. You probably do not own this DLC.